# Unable to authenticate github and npm

Tags: github, npm-publish, npm-request

```
 $ npm login --scope=@username --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com
 
 $ Username: username
 
 $ Password: ********
 
 $ Email: (this IS public) example@gmail.com
 
 $ npm ERR! code E401
 
 $ npm ERR! 401 Unauthorized - PUT $ https://npm.pkg.github.com/-/user/org.couchdb.user:forinda - Error authenticating user: Requires authentication
 
 $npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
 
 $npm ERR!     /home/orinda/.npm/_logs/2021-10-15T02_25_19_104Z-debug.log
```

**Unable to authenticate npm registry and github**
I get a 401 error on filling in my password
How can I fix this

Answer (score 6):

Use your `github-username` in the `username`, use your `github-auth_token` as your `password` and you're good to go.

[image: Image with the directive on how to fill the login credentials]

A link to the same is here: [Github docs](https://github.community/t/github-packages-not-working-cant-publish-packages/159712)

Comment: Link is dead no answer on archive.org: https://web.archive.org/web/20211026083942/https://github.community/t/github-packages-not-working-cant-publish-packages/159712

Comment: You can read through this [Github docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/publishing-packages/publishing-nodejs-packages)